# Feature flags in JHipster applications

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, jhipster

What is the recommended way / best-practice of using feature flags in jhipster / angular based application?

I have modified my **webpack.dev.js**:

```
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE': true
        }),
```

I have also tried:

```
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE': JSON.stringify(true)
        }),
```

Unfortunately I can't use *EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE* in any TS component / code this way:

```
Webpack: Starting ...

  √ Compile modules
  > Build modules (75%)
    → 0 of 2 modules :: src/main/webapp/app/entities/microservice/microservice-dashboard/microservice-card/microservice-card.component.ts ~ internal

ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/entities/microservice/microservice-dashboard/microservice-card/microservice-card.component.ts:21:31 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE'.

21     const hideSomeComponent = EXPERIMENTAL_FEATURE;

                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: In angular, you can use the environment configuration for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not how you define the constant but how you use it in your typescript code.

Look at how it is done for `BUILD_TIMESTAMP`, it's defined using DefinePlugin webpack plugin as you did but then the key point is to use `process.env.BUILD_TIMESTAMP` to define a new constant `BUILD_TIMESTAMP` in `app.constant.ts` and export it.

Then you import it in `microservice-card.component.ts`

```
import { BUILD_TIMESTAMP} from 'app/app.constants';
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need, many thanks and best wishes!